# Text file Iterating, Slicing, breaking bigger lines into smaller lines of equal size

Tags: python, text, iteration, slice

I am new in handling text files in Python. I have a huge text file (2 million lines) a.txt which looks like this:

```
1 0
34715 0 1 8 0 29 5 5 11 4 8 4 150 0 1
0
2200859 1 4 8 1 18 5 5 10 189 8 4 309 0 4 
0
749279 1 1 5 4 38 5 5 0 157 8 4 370 0 2106576 1 1 5 4 38 5 5 1 157 6 18 370 0  2140134 1 1 5 4 38 5 5 1 157 6 13 370 0  2140408 0 1 5 4 38 5 5 1 157 6 16 370 0  1
0
1149510 0 5 8 2 19 5 2 1 111 5 4 388 0  2
0
471429 0 1 6 0 29 5 5 11 4 8 18 414 0  2629646 0 1 6 0 29 5 5 11 4 8 4 414 0  1
0
48249 0 1 8 0 30 5 5 1 115 0 6 458 0  3
0
1515836 0 0 8 2 7 5 3 1 163 2 4 522 0  1516727 0 0 8 2 7 5 3 1 163 2 4 522 0  1516995 0 0 8 2 7 5 3 1 163 2 4 522 0
```

- 1st line contains 0 1
- 2nd line contains 15 numbers starting from 34715, 0, ... ,1
- 3rd line contain only one number 0
- 4th line contains again 15 numbers
- 5th line contains again only one number 0
- 6th line contains 57 numbers

and so on ....
I want a new text file b.txt which will look something like this:

```
1 0
34715 0 1 8 0 29 5 5 11 4 8 4 150 0 
1 0
2200859 1 4 8 1 18 5 5 10 189 8 4 309 0  
4 0
749279 1 1 5 4 38 5 5 0 157 8 4 370 0  
2106576 1 1 5 4 38 5 5 1 157 6 18 370 0  
2140134 1 1 5 4 38 5 5 1 157 6 13 370 0  
2140408 0 1 5 4 38 5 5 1 157 6 16 370 0 
1 0
1149510 0 5 8 2 19 5 2 1 111 5 4 388 0  
2 0
471429 0 1 6 0 29 5 5 11 4 8 18 414 0  
2629646 0 1 6 0 29 5 5 11 4 8 4 414 0  
1 0
48249 0 1 8 0 30 5 5 1 115 0 6 458 0  
3 0
1515836 0 0 8 2 7 5 3 1 163 2 4 522 0  
1516727 0 0 8 2 7 5 3 1 163 2 4 522 0  
1516995 0 0 8 2 7 5 3 1 163 2 4 522 0
```

This has

- 1st line same 0 1
- 2nd line contains 14 numbers starting from 34715, 0, 1, ...., 0
- 3rd line now contains two numbers 1, 0
- 4th line contains 14  numbers
- 5th contains two numbers 4, 0

then from line 6th to 9th each contain 14 numbers

and so on

This can be achieved by two steps I guess -

1. The last digit from of the bigger lines (length >1) of a.text  is shifted in the next line just before 0 and it will look like 1 0, 4 0 etc in b.text
2. After this, the bigger lines with length > 14 will be broken into more lines and the number of lines will be equal to the above digit i.e if it is 4 0 then there will be 4 lines(rows) each of length 14.

Example - 6th line in a.txt with 57 numbers will be converted into 4 lines each of length 14 and the last number is already shifted in the next line.

I tried a few things but was unsuccessful

```
with open('words.txt','r+') as f, open("B.txt", "w") as b:
    for line in f:
      index = 0
      if line.count(' ') > 1:
        words = line.split(' ')
        temp = words[-1]
```

With this code I am able to get the last number of bigger lines but how to add them in the next line before 0? Also after this how to do second step?

Comment: Split every line into a list of words. Get the length of that list. If it's less than 14, continue to the next line. Otherwise, partition it into blocks of length 14 (ignoring any remainder). Now re-join each block and add it to a list. The length of that list gives the `n 0` line, and the blocks it contains gives the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to solve it.

```
f=open('sachin.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
new_file=open('updated.txt','w')
new_file.write(lines[0])
for i in range(1,len(lines)-1,2):
    l1=lines[i]
    l2=lines[i+1]
    l1.strip("\n")
    l2.strip("\n")
    l1=l1.split()
    l2=l2.split()
    l2.append(l1[-1])
    l2[0],l2[1]=l2[1],l2[0]
    temp=[]
    count=0
    j=0
    while j<(len(l1)):
        if count==13:
            temp.append(l1[j])
            new_temp=" ".join(temp)
            new_file.write(new_temp+'\n')
            count=0
            temp=[]
            j+=1
        else:
            temp.append(l1[j])
            j+=1
            count+=1
    l2=" ".join(l2)
    new_file.write(l2+"\n")
new_file.close()            
f.close()
```